# showing only the last two rows and hide the rest

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to have a short Google docs script which makes it possible to automatically see only the last two rows in a Google spreadsheet. So what I want is, when I add new data in a new row and hit ENTER, it automatically shows only the last two rows and hide all other rows.

I self started with the below codes but I don't know what to do further. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
function HideDone() {     
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var test = sheet.getLastRow() - 2;   
    sheet.hideRows(1,test);
}
```

Comment: You need to use either an `onEdit()` function, which is a simple trigger, or an On Change installable trigger.  Whatever cell is the last cell that you enter data in, use that column number to test for whether that column was just updated or not.  [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)  You can use the `range` property of the event object:  `var range = e.range;` and then from `range` get the column number.  `var editedColumn = range.getColumn()`

Answer (score 0):

This task can be accomplished with an onEdit() Trigger.
Code:

```
function hide () {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('REPLACE');
 ss.hideRows(1, ss.getLastRow()-2);
}
```

Set a trigger -> select hide function -> event on edit